# Inherit/pass-through settings in sbt subproject?

Tags: scala, sbt

Brand new to sbt (using 1.x) and trying to get this setup working as intended, but I seem to be missing something.

I have a nested directory structure as follows:

```
ProjectRoot/
  AggregationPoint/
    DockerSubproject/
```

Each directory has its own build.sbt, and the root is something like this:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(name...)
  .aggregate(aggregationPoint, fizz, buzz)

lazy val aggregationPoint = (project in file("AggregationPoint"))
  .settings(commonSettings)
  .enablePlugins(DockerPlugin, GitVersioning)

// other projects using commonSettings are omitted to avoid distraction
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(...)
```

DockerSubproject builds an image, and that part is working fine. However, the config for tagging the image correctly (defined in `commonSettings`) isn't being passed from ProjectRoot, through AggregationPoint, and into DockerSubproject. It works if I remove AggregationPoint from the equation (and just point at DockerSubproject directly) so I know the config values themselves are correct and that DockerSubproject picks them up.

`AggregationPoint/build.sbt` looks something like this:

```
lazy val aggregationPoint = (project in file("."))
  .settings(name...)
  .aggregate(dockerSubproject)

lazy val dockerSubproject = (project in file("DockerSubproject"))
  .enablePlugins(DockerPlugin, GitVersioning)
```

Do I need to access the passed-in settings somehow and explicitly call `.settings(...)` again? Is what I'm wanting to do even possible? Is there a best-practices way of handling this sort of thing?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The best practice is to have a single sbt file, including all data you need to all of your subprojects. Why do you have this kind of structure?

Comment: Not all of the subprojects are homogeneous, so we were thinking of keeping specific (and more verbose) configs in each subproject's built.sbt to avoid noise that would likely result from putting everything into a central file.

Comment: You can aggregate settings in Lists and just apply batches of settings as needed. Lists of settings and dependencies can be stores in `project` as normal `.scala` files

Comment: Regardless of how you structure your project, settings in the aggregating subproject don't apply to the aggregated ones. Aggregation is like a "weak" dependency. You need to apply your common setting to the docker subproject, not the aggregation point.